# Get number of sheet excel in python

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

How get number of sheet in below python example?

```
file = self.excel_file.decode('base64')

excel_fileobj = TemporaryFile('wb+')
excel_fileobj.write(file)
excel_fileobj.seek(0)

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_fileobj, data_only=True)

sheet_number= ???

sheet = workbook[workbook.get_sheet_names()[0]]


for row in sheet.rows:
            print(row[1].value)
```

sheet_number=????

Any solutin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing worksheets using xlwt 'get\_sheet' method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14587271/accessing-worksheets-using-xlwt-get-sheet-method)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`workbook.worksheets` contains a list of worksheet objects.

To get the number of worksheets:

```
sheet_number = len(workbook.worksheets)
```

Simplest way to iterate over all worksheets:

```
for ws in workbook.worksheets:
    print ws.title
```